# Squiggly/wavy/interlaced display

Tags: 20.04, display, 21.04

I'm on a MSI PE70 2QE Laptop with an NVIDIA Geforce GTX960M.

I was running Ubuntu 21.04 and since I've installed all the latest software updates my display is acting up.

It doesn't flicker but it's kind of squiggly looking interlacing or something (best description I could come up with :p).

I'm running a dual boot setup, and on Windows there's no problem, so I guess I can rule out the display being broken.

I've tried installing proprietary drivers (several of them), tried rolling back the updates and even uninstalled Ubuntu and installed Ubuntu 20.04 but the problem persists now.

Hope someone can help me out!

---

Some pictures of the problem (pictures are all taken during startup but the problem persists when in UI/OS as well):
[image: Image 1]
[image: Close]
[image]

Comment: Do you have problems with completely booted system?

Comment: Yes the problem persists!

Comment: Then please be more specific about laptop/desktop model, its video adapter and its driver.

Comment: I'm on a MSI PE70 2QE Laptop with an NVIDIA Geforce GTX960M. I do not have any drivers at this time because the screens taken now are from running Ubuntu 20.04 from USB (Before installation).  ALthough as i told in my initial question the problem was visible on (installed versions of) 21.04 20.04 with standard and latest proprietary drivers

Comment: The MSI logo is independent of the OS, it appear before the OS is loaded. Whatever the problem is, there's no relation with Ubuntu. It's either hardware failure or some glitch in the firmware (UEFI). I don't understand why then you're posting this question and even less the bounty.

Comment: Hi @ChanganAuto I was posting it here as the problem started immediately after I installed system updates. Also the logo isn't entirely seperate of the OS as the Ubuntu logo is showing as and the MSI logo when booting Windows is fine!  I think we can rule out hardware because when I start my dual boot (windows) the problem doesn't exist.